# Wp-admin error message after login

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress website and when I am trying to login into WordPress dashboard error message shows:

> "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.".

It is working before some days. I tried deactivating plugins but no result.

Comment: Did you checked after clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Yes, i tried refreshing it using ctrl + f5 several times.

Comment: Please refer this http://www.naijatechzone.com/wp-admin-login-error-sorry-you-are-not-allowed-to-access-this-page/

Comment: will it helps in this case ? because, there is no change of table prefix.

Comment: can you rename plugins folder then check ? don't deactive plugin,also can you provide link of your site so i can give better response

Comment: its http://apimindia.net

Comment: @dhi_m i have tried this solution given by you but no result.

Comment: @RaviSukhadia i have provided link of my website

Comment: @shubhamshah there is many possiblity for this error 1) if your wordpress updated then this problem raise 2) change in wp_capabilities 3) change in htaccess 4) Security Plugin 5) Checking that my user has wp_capabilities set to a:1:{s:13:”administrator”;b:1;}

you can try this option also.

Comment: @RaviSukhadia i have installed members plugin for checking capabilities and all permission granted for administrator role. No security plugins.

Comment: @shubhamshah can you check your wordpress updated to new version? if yes then might be it causes error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163318/discussion-between-shubham-shah-and-ravi-sukhadia).